# Why does \ExecuteMetaData break my paragraphs?

Tags: paragraphs, input, catchfile

I have a lot of content to assemble in several different ways and would like to use excerpts from one file in another. I have specified:

```
\usepackage{catchfilebetweentags}
```

I then have an external file with tagged sections something like this in it:

```
%<*tag>
\section{section: tag}

paragraph one

paragraph two
%</tag>
```

I can suck these into another document easily:

```
\ExecuteMetaData[bits.tex]{tag}
```

The problem is that when it comes over, there are no longer any pargraphs. The `\section` is properly formatted, but after that I can't make normal paragraphs work for love or money. Even adding `\para` has no effect.

Stragely enough if I just input the file it works fine:

```
\input{bits.tex}
```

...works as expected. The only problem is this gets the *whole* file, and I only want select portions of it. I looked at organizing the bits file with `\input`s of their own but the system quickly gets messy and hard for my copy-writers to work on.

How do I get a normal paragraph environment back in content pulled over via `\ExecuteMetaData`?

Comment: It's much worse: endlines are discarded by `\ExecuteMetaData`, so you even get no space between `one` and `paragraph`. The package sets `\endlinechar=-1` when reading the file.

Comment: Take a look at the [clipboard](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/clipboard)  package.

Comment: @Fran That is an interesting package, but it requires you to run tex an all the possible source files _before_ you run it on the destination. That would rather complicate the life of my project rather that simplify it. It seems much more useful for back-referencing repeated content within the same document rather than for handling externals.

Comment: @egreg So you are saying not only is it a witch, but it's _the_ Wicked Witch of the West™? Is there no way to make it behave? Or a sane alternative that accomplishes the same task with less mucking about in my whitespace?

Comment: @Caleb For a complicated life, use a simple script `:)` In Linux could be some as simple as `for file in *.tex; do pdflatex "$file"; done`

Comment: @Fran My day job is writing shell scripts, so believe me [I know how to make that work](http://unix.stackexchange.com/users/1925/caleb). The problem is I need this to also work at a couple windows based print shops and the desktop gui used by some of my content authors needs to reliably show them a proper preview. Requiring a stack of things to be done rather that just doing what these people and apps expect to work is bound to be the source of future pain.

Comment: @Caleb Sorry, I do not look at you profile before giving the advice. Fools rush in where angels fear to tread `:)`

Comment: @Fran Please accept my apologies if that came out wrong; I wouldn't have expected you to know what I do or don't know and I do appreciate the effort to be helpful. I only wanted to communicate that I wasn't rejecting your proposed solution out of ignorance of fear of the unknown.

Comment: @Caleb Is the tagged file automatically generated or typed?

Comment: @egreg Unfortunately, there will be some of both. My hope was to make use of a collection of single subject article files that are usable as fully finished documents in their own right (and that are already maintained by hand) as sources for a compilation document that uses pre-defined parts of those inline in a different setting. If that works I wanted to use exactly the same system (no extra learning curve for those working on the compilation docs) to pull data from files that I generate from a database source and periodically make available along with the other source documents.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can provide your own "tag" system via conditionals. Let me explain:

For each tag `<tag>`, define a conditional `\if<tag>` via `\newif\if<tag>`. Then, inside your document, brace the tagged group using `\if<tag>`...`\fi`. Now you can use `\inputbetweentags{<tag>}{<filename>}` to insert the file contents between the newly generated "tags".

Here is a minimal example:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\setlength{\parindent}{0pt}% Just for this example
\usepackage{filecontents}% http://ctan.org/pkg/filecontents

\newif\iftagA% <tagA>
\newif\iftagB% <tagB>

\begin{filecontents*}{filename.tex}
\iftagA% <tagA>
\section{Section A}
A paragraph one

A paragraph two
\fi% </tagA>
\iftagB% <tagB>
\section{Section B}
B paragraph one

B paragraph two
\fi% </tagB>
\end{filecontents*}

\newcommand{\inputbetweentag}[2]{{% \inputbetweentag{<tag>}{<filename>}
  \expandafter\let\csname if#1\endcsname\iftrue% Make "tag" true
  \input{#2}}}% Input file
\begin{document}
Number 1

\inputbetweentag{tagA}{filename.tex}

Number 2

\inputbetweentag{tagB}{filename.tex}

Number 3
\end{document}
```

Comment: If I'm understanding this correctly `filecontents` is only for the purpose of showing this example as one file instead of two, but I would have to have the `\newif\iftagX` bits defined in the source file, not the target that I am importing to correct? And the `% <tag>` comments in this setup really are just comments, not functional hooks like they were with `catchfilebetweentags`, right`

Comment: @Caleb: Yes [`filecontents`](http://ctan.org/pkg/filecontents) was just for this example, and so was the use of commented `<tags>`. Yes, you would define the `\newif\iftagX` in your source file, since their values have to be set before including the file.

Answer (score 6):

Here is a workaround, that avoids setting `\endlinechar` to an unwanted value. I don't know whether there are side effects.

```
\begin{filecontents*}{calebits.tex}
%<*tag>
\section{section: tag}

paragraph one

paragraph two
%</tag>
\end{filecontents*}

\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{catchfilebetweentags}
\makeatletter
\def\CatchFBT@sanitize{%
   \@sanitize
   \@makeother\{%
   \@makeother\}%
%   \endlinechar=`\^^J% <--- This line modified
}% \CatchFBT@sanitize
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\ExecuteMetaData[calebits.tex]{tag}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: This causes an error if there is a comment in the catched part, giving `Runaway text?` ... `! File ended while scanning text of \CatchFBT@tok. <inserted text> }`

Comment: @JasperHabicht I’m not sure whether comments are supported at all inn the tagged file.

Comment: @egreg They are. The doc (page 2) says, that in-line comments are normally ignored, and non line-comments are always ignored.

Comment: @JasperHabicht Well, you’ve found a side effect.